# connecting mongoDB without credentials also

Tags: mongodb

I just started working on mongoDb. I created 2 types of users. First type behaves like a super admin. And second admin can access only particular database only. Everything is working fine. But if I try to connect mongoDb without credentials also, it is connecting and can do everything. How can i avoid to connect mongodb server without authentication.

Comment: Either you made a mistake when applying rights to the DB or collection, or you applied it to the wrong collection. You may also be connecting as the superadmin without realizing it. In all cases if the rights are applied correctly and you try to do something without the proper authorization Mongodb will not allow it. Check the DB users and authorization with Mongo shell.

Comment: I created rights using shell. First I crated super admin in admin database and users collection, then I added regular users on particular database. If I starts with authentication everything working properly. Even though not authentication also it working. Can you give proper suggestions to solve the problem.